# Are Retrofit and Okhttp abandoned?

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, okio

- Retrofit Version 2.9.0 (2020-05-20)
- Okhttp Version 4.10.0 (2022-06-12) Version 5.0.0-alpha.11 (2022-12-24)

Retrofit has 36 opened pull request and 147 opened bug, Okhttp 9 opened pull request and 161 opened bug.

I know that this question hurts, and that we all consider Retrofit and Okhttp like children, but i need to ask:

Are Retrofit and Okhttp abandoned?

Comment: You have no idea of what you are talking about. They just released the stable of the Retrofit - Kotlin serialization adapter in Jake repository, and it will shortly be imported in the main Retrofit repository. There's not much that need to be done on Retrofit and Okhttp. Most of the effort is going to Okio, as far as I know to port it to Kotlin multiplatform, next okttp will and probably retrofit next too.

Comment: This is a question for the owners / maintainers of said libraries and off-topic for SO.

Comment: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3181#issuecomment-516677686 worth reading

Comment: @DanieleSegato why so aggressive?

Comment: @JustSightseeing KMM is not the only thing to do, not?

Comment: @AlessandroScarozza Because you are criticizing one of the best open source project and people contributing to the android community with a nonsense argument.

Comment: @DanieleSegato 3 year from last stable release is enough for me to make the question. anyway i love retrofit and okhttp

Comment: @AlessandroScarozza there are libraries I use everyday that didn't got updated in decades. 
And you are too when you use most of the language standard APIs. There'ss no need to update something that does everything you need already. That approach to evaluating any project is flawed.

Comment: @DanieleSegato one thing is the public API one thing is the internal implementation. an abandoned project does not receive fixes even regarding security bugs. considering that they are libraries that concern the network layer, I think my question is important

Comment: I'm sorry if I was blunt. But no. Even than, you could have a software without security bugs for years after release, especially if it hasn't been touched. For small, focused, well written libraries like retrofit, okio etc this is very likely to be the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OkHttp had a new 4.x release a couple weeks ago.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/docs/changelogs/changelog_4x.md#version-4110

A new 5.x alpha release is coming soon! We were hoping to ship 5.0 final before Google I/0 2023 but we missed that deadline. The new 5.0 alphas have some unstable APIs but the behaviour is pretty solid.

Comment: your response in less than 24 hours is enough for me to understand that the project is not abandoned. Thank you

Comment: Good to see an update to the 4.x release! Were these fixes already present in the 5.x alpha releases?

We plan to use the 5.x version for our upcoming release because of the new Kotlin-friendly APIs and this statement made with 5.0.0-alpha.7: _"The alpha releases in the 5.0.0 series have production-quality code and an unstable API. We expect to make changes to the APIs introduced in 5.0.0-alpha.X. These releases are safe for production use and 'alpha' strictly signals that we're still experimenting with some new APIs. If you're eager for the fixes or features below, please upgrade."_

Comment: Yep. We’re currently revising our plans to make 5.x a little less ambitious on multiplatform.